# Dir /s の実行に時間がかかり過ぎる

Tags: コマンドプロンプト

`Dir /s`と打ち込むと、3分ぐらいファイルが出て止まりません。短縮してファイルを表示するにはどうしたらいいですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir /s /w` とか？
もしくは、`dir /s > dir.txt` みたいにtext fileへ出力すれば3分もかからんと思いますよ。

まぁ、実行するディレクトリが悪いだけ気がしますけど...
必要なディレクトリに移動してから実行する方が良いと思いますよ。

Answer (score 0):

`dir`コマンドに`/s`スイッチを付けた場合、サブディレクトリ以下をすべて辿って表示しようとするため、実行したディレクトリによっては結果を表示し終わるまでに時間がかかる場合があります。

サブディレクトリを辿って表示したいのであれば、以下のように`more`コマンドに結果をパイプ(`|`)経由で渡すことで1画面ずつ中断しながら結果を表示できます。(EnterキーやSpaceキーで画面送りができます)

`C:\> dir /s | more`